# How do I create compound custom fields?

Tags: custom-object, custom-field

I'd like some of the custom fields on my custom object to function similarly to the existing compound fields on standard objects (e.g. BillingStreet in BillingAddress).  Existing documentation I can find https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/compound_fields_address.htm describes how to pull data from compound fields, but not how to create new ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't currently create custom compound fields, except for Geolocation data types (which have a longitude and latitude component). See [Create custom compound fields](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DjHlAAK) and [Add a new Standard field type: Address](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrVWAA0) for ideas that have been proposed to salesforce. The Address type is currently under consideration to add to the road map. I'd suggest voting on these ideas so we can maybe get them in the future.